# Select everything but a list of columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to select the negation of a given list from pandas dataframe?. For instance, say I have the following dataframe

```
T1_V2  T1_V3 T1_V4 T1_V5 T1_V6 T1_V7 T1_V8
1     15      3      2     N     B     N         
4     16     14      5     H     B     N            
1     10     10      5     N     K     N
```

and I want to get out all columns but column T1_V6. I would normally do that this way:

```
df = df[["T1_V2","T1_V3","T1_V4","T1_V5","T1_V7","T1_V8"]]
```

My question is on whether there is a way to this the other way around, something like this

```
df = df[!["T1_V6"]]
```

Comment: You could use a list comprehension `df[[column for column in df.columns if column != 'T1_V6']]`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do:

```
df[df.columns.difference(["T1_V6"])]
```

Notes from comments:

- This will sort the columns. If you don't want to sort call `difference` with `sort=False`
- The `difference` won't raise error if the dropped column name doesn't exist. If you want to raise error in case the column doesn't exist then use drop as suggested in other answers: `df.drop(["T1_V6"])`
  `

Comment: I accepted the answer because it's the most compact and gets the job done. However, I am receiving this warning `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1353: FutureWarning: using '-' to provide set differences with Indexes is deprecated, use .difference()
  "use .difference()",FutureWarning)`

Comment: Hmm.. strangely I didn't get the warning. I added the difference method to the answer. It's almost as simple.

Comment: The set minus doesn't actually work for numeric column names so for them you must use difference.

Comment: Same basic idea, but what about `df[ df.columns.drop('T1_V7') ]`

Comment: There is one difference though: `.drop` throws an error if you try to drop column or columns which don't exist in the DataFrame, while `.difference` doesn't.  That is good to take into account when you are choosing which one to use.

Comment: Pandas sort the remaining columns by default. Sometimes this can be confusing but is easily fixed by setting the `sort` parameter to `False`; `df[df.columns.difference(["T1_V6"], sort=False)]`. Now, this is probably not an issue in the original post but might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, you can also easily use `drop` for this:

```
df.drop(["T1_V6"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to exclude columns that you don't want:

```
df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['T1_V6'])]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `DataFrame.drop()`:

```
columns_to _exclude = ['T1_V6']
old_dataframe = #Has all columns
new_dataframe = old_data_frame.drop(columns_to_exclude, axis = 1)
```

You could use inplace to make changes to the original dataframe itself

```
old_dataframe.drop(columns_to_exclude, axis = 1, inplace = True)
#old_dataframe is changed
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[col for col in df.columns if col != 'T1_V6']
```